# Displaying flexbox centered but align items left like text align left

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am trying to setup these divs to display in the centre but keep their items displayed left, like `text-align: left` would do.

Here's my example: https://jsfiddle.net/gr5Lmos1/

```css
#donateList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.donateItem {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-self: center;
}

.donateItem * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.donateItem p {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.donateItem img {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="donateList">
  <div class="donateItem">
    <img src="/images/icons/bitcoin.png">
    <p>Bitcoin:</p>
    <p>fkewjhf;eiwhf;iewfhwehfewifhew</p>
  </div>
  <div class="donateItem">
    <img src="/images/icons/paypal.png">
    <p>Paypal:</p>
    <p>eijfhewfwifhefefewf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the donateItem's contents to all display left but keep all the donateItem's divs centre as they are now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are open to include another *wrapper* in your markup, it is easy:

1. Use `align-items: flex-start` (or let it take the default `stretch` value) for the `#donateList`
2. Center align vertically and horizontally the new wrapper div.

See demo below (also removed some *redundant* styles):

```css
main { /* ADDED */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#donateList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start; /* CHANGED */
  /*align-self: center;*/
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.donateItem {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  /*align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-self: center;*/
}

.donateItem * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.donateItem p {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.donateItem img{
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="donateList">
    <div class="donateItem">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <p>Bitcoin:</p>
      <p>fkewjhf;eiwhf;iewfhwehfewifhew</p>
    </div>
    <div class="donateItem">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
      <p>Paypal:</p>
      <p>eijfhewfwifhefefewf</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is good, didn't think to try that. I just made a new wrapper/ container to replace main.

Answer (score 2):

You Have To Just Do This:

```
#donateList
{ 
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

And Add `display:flex;` in `.donateItem` and `.donateItem p`#

```css
#donateList

{
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    
}

.donateItem
{
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-self: center;
  display:flex;
}

.donateItem p
{
  vertical-align: bottom;
 display:flex;
}


.donateItem *
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.donateItem img
{
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="donateList">

<div class="donateItem">

  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/froyoshark/enkel/96/Bitcoin-icon.png">

  <p>Bitcoin:</p>

  <p>fkewjhf;eiwhf;iewfhwehfewifhew</p>

</div>

<div class="donateItem">

  <img src="http://axisj.com/assets/images/donate-how-paypal.png">

  <p>Paypal:</p>

  <p>eijfhewfwifhefefewf</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, but it's a bit hacky and the container width needs to be adjusted to the particular situation. The container gets these settings for centering inside the body:

```
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
```

...and the flex items get `align-self: flex-start;` for left-alignment inside the container:

```css
#donateList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-self: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.donateItem {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.donateItem * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.donateItem p {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.donateItem img {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="donateList">
  <div class="donateItem">
    <img src="/images/icons/bitcoin.png">
    <p>Bitcoin:</p>
    <p>fkewjhf;eiwhf;iewfhwehfewifhew</p>
  </div>
  <div class="donateItem">
    <img src="/images/icons/paypal.png">
    <p>Paypal:</p>
    <p>eijfhewfwifhefefewf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers, changing items alignment to `flex-start` and making the container as wide as the longest item via `width: max-content` makes it possible to center it with usual `margin:auto`:

```css
#donateList {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

.donateItem {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.donateItem * {
  display: inline-block;
}

.donateItem p {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.donateItem img {
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div id="donateList">
  <div class="donateItem">
    <img src="/images/icons/bitcoin.png">
    <p>Bitcoin:</p>
    <p>fkewjhf;eiwhf;iewfhwehfewifhew</p>
  </div>
  <div class="donateItem">
    <img src="/images/icons/paypal.png">
    <p>Paypal:</p>
    <p>eijfhewfwifhefefewf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the browser support of `max-content` is [far from ideal](http://caniuse.com/#search=max-content), so @kukkuz's solution with an extra wrapper is probably more practical (unless left alignment of the container is the acceptable graceful degradation for you).