# How can I align this text so that it starts in the same position?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to align the symbol's column so that it all starts in the same position because as you can see here, all the names start in different positions. I tried doing it with a flex and justifying it to the flex-end but it is not working. If anyone can help me with this CSS issue I would really appreciate it.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import './tracker.css'

function Tracker() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await axios('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false')
        setData(result.data)
      }
      fetchData()
  }, [])

console.log(data)
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="tracker__names">
            <p>Coins</p>
            <p>Symbol</p>
            <p>Price</p>
            <p>Market Cap</p>
          </div>
            {data.map((coins) => {
                return (
                  <>
                  <div className="tracker__main">
                    <div>
                        <img src={coins.image} className="tracker__image"/>
                      {coins.id}
                    </div>
                    <div className="tracker__symbol">
                        <p>{coins.symbol}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {coins.current_price}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        {coins.market_cap}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tracker
```

CSS:

```
.tracker__main {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-around;
}

.tracker__image {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
}

.tracker__names {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tracker__symbol {
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying flexbox centered but align items left like text align left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46569692/displaying-flexbox-centered-but-align-items-left-like-text-align-left)

Comment: no it doesnt work either

Comment: If you post your rendered html, we could try it

Comment: isn't the rendered HTML after the return? or what do you mean?

Comment: No, the rendered HTML is what you see in your browser. Not the angular code.

Comment: isn't the picture? Or you mean making a live code?